Closed question : Low-Power Multidevice Wireless Communication : Real-Time Data Between 12 Portable MCUs Within 10m
Low-Power Multidevice Wireless Communication : Real-Time Data Between 12 Portable MCUs Within 10m [closed] was closed for off-topic with regards to product selection, but I was asking about what is involved in the design : which communication protocols to use (to likely be followed up with the types of parts which would be needed to perform such a communication).
I did state that I am looking at STM32 MCUs in case there is a known protocol which comes with the series standard, but my specific question was surrounding the type of communication to use with bidirectional communication, multiple nodes, and real-time responsiveness.
(When I referenced existing research performed, I included the past answers that I found on this site, which did refer to specific RF modulator parts or part series, but I don't believe that referencing answers from the past makes my general design question in bad faith, and those answers are all from 10+ years ago, so they are potentially obsolete).
Would removing evidence that past answers referred to specific parts make my question more on topic?

The question needs to address "locale" - that is, where in the world is it intended to be used? This must always be known for wireless projects, since there are just a few bands that are acceptable world-wide. 2.4GHz being one such rare exception.

Do what the link says:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Describe the problem you want to solve, not ask for what to buy. Shopping questions are useless, they are usually only good to that person, SE's mission is to build a repository of good questions and answers and shopping questions don't fit here. Design questions do:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Can you elaborate further which part of the question involves shipping?

(I said cost cheap, but what I intended and perhaps what I should have said is non-proprietary / open-source wireless communication method.)

@kando It is still off topic, please describe your problem

Alright — I think I modified the question in the right direction. If not, please let me know and I will happily modify further.

I'm still unsure — are communications protocols considered products, even if I'm seeking non-proprietary means?

Is this an electrical design question (hardware?) or a software question?
